# Implementing virtual methods in other parent-branch than they are declared in

Tags: c++, virtual, multiple-inheritance

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Grandma
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class Mom : public Grandma{};

class Dad
{
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "dad's foo impl"; }
};

class Me : public Mom, public Dad{};

int main()
{
    Me m;
    m.foo();
}
```

and getting : `cannot instantiate abstract class`

I know what this error means, I know I can't instantiate Grandma because of pure-virtual.

But why can't I instantiate Me, when compiler knows I am derived from Mom and Dad and Dad has `foo` implemented?

I know I can fixed it by adding `foo` into `Me` and inside it call e.g. `Dad::foo`, but I am afraid it is not solution for my case.

Is it really necessary to have virtual method implementation between its declaration and instantiated object (when traversing "class hierarchy graph")? See ASCI graph

```
    A
    |
B1  B2
  \ |   
   C1  C2
    | /
    |/
    D
    |
    E
```

When I want to instantiate E and have virtual declaration in A, the only way to make it run is to define it in A, B2, C1, D or E?
and similarly when is virtual declaration in C2 only way is to define it in C2, D or E?

I know this may be silly question, but I had a loooong day and can not think anymore.

Please, do not answer just with - "It is not possible", but try to add explanation why not.

Thank you!

**EDIT** -- foo() in `Dad` is of course should not be private

Comment: your `Dad` class doesn't derive from `Grandma` class, so `Dad::foo` doesn't override base class pure virtual function. Additionally, your derivation is not virtual, so you have two separate subobjects in `Me`

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev There is no diamond inheritance here so virtual inheritance should have no effect.

Comment: @Mark -- that's correct, but that wasn't my point. If the `Dad` were to derive from `Grandma`, there would have been a diamond, and the same error, making the derivation virtual would have solved the latter.

Comment: Yeah, dad should have a mom, thus be derived from grandma.. Perhaps just bad names for an example :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no relation** between `Dad` class and `Grandma` class. `Dad` and `Grandma` are two completely different classes. Given that the method in `Dad` is not considered as an implementation of the pure virtual method in `Grandma` and has to be implemented in the `Me` class.

When you derive from an **Abstract class**(class containing atleast one pure virtual function) the deriving class needs to override and implement **ALL** the pure virtual member functions of the Base Class. If not, the deriving class becomes Abstract too, same applies to the classes deriving from the derived class further down the hierarchy.

Comment: Would adding `using Dad::foo` to `Me` be sufficient to meet this condition?

Comment: Your answer would be clearer if you avoided using a valid operator as an abbreviation for the word _and_

Comment: @rcollyer: `Dad::foo` is private in `Dad` so it is not accessible anyhow, considering it was `protected` **NO**, You will still have to provide an implementation in `Me`.

Comment: @Nicola Musatti: Do you mean replacing `&` with a `and`, And did you really downvote for this reason?

Comment: @acl, true. Wasn't paying attention to that, but I'd presume that if it was publicly (or even protected) accessible than it would work then. True?

Comment: @rcollyer: I assumed you did'nt think of that & did add that it won't work even if it was `protected` or `public`.

Comment: @Als -- you don't need to make it `protected` or `public`, in fact better not to expose the details of implementation. But when you have a hierarchy, *is-a* means that your calls are going via base class (pointer or reference), so `static_cast<Grandma&>(m).foo();` would work (provided the other problems resolved).

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: While what you state is correct. I never advocated making anything `public` or `protected`, I was answering the OP's query of how the behavior will be if `Dad::foo` was `public` or `protected` & if s/he publicized it in `Me` class. I don't know If you did'nt read the entire conversation or I was not clear enough.

Comment: @Als: I had to read your answer more than once to get your meaning, so yes I did vote it down.

Comment: @Nicola Musatti: I find it amusing that that you would downvote someone's answer because **You** did not understand it. I am glad though OP understood it and asked the Q's which indicated so. :)

Comment: @Als -- I find it amusing anybody would care much about up/down-voting; and how to vote is a personal issue -- don't ask, don't argue.

Comment: @Nicola: Welcome to Stackoverflow! (No BCB user anymore? `:)` What happened?) It's good you suggested this, I even agree with you, but please do not downvote this answer over such a minor stylistic disagreement. Those are mostly pointed out here, while downvoting is usually spared for factual problems. I'll edit the answer. Please undo your downvote afterwards.

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: The trend is really outrageous and supporting it even more. Downvotes are welcome but they should be atleast justifiable not for reasons like `avoid using a valid operator as an abbreviation for the word and` or `I had to read your answer more than once to get your meaning`

Comment: All, I think we should table this discussion for Meta or Chat. These types of things tend to get out of hand.

Comment: @Als: I'm rather new around here so maybe downvoting your answer was too harsh: as you may have noticed I did follow my friend sbi's advice. That said I'm still convinced that my point is valid and that we all should do our best to make our answers as clear as possible. Yours wasn't as clear as it could have been and I find it sad that you failed to acknowledge it. Anyway, I'll take Code Monkey's point and close the discussion here.

Comment: @Nicola Musatti: Bygones are bygones, lets start afresh, Welcome abroad SO & hope to see you around more.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you're right that you have to implement the virtual method in the path between original declaration and final instantiated object. Objects multiply inherited in can't implement that interface.

So from the question it sounds like you're trying to implement a parent interface in a child class by inheriting from the implementor. Instead of that approach, did you consider instead having the parent class delegate the work to a strategy pattern and then select the proper strategy in your child class. Then you can still compose implementations together and don't have to worry about the many complexities of multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a virtual function is only overridden by implementations provided by classes inheriting (potentially through several layers) from the class where the virtual function is originally declared.

However, depending on what you are actually trying to accomplish, [Sister Class Delegation](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.10) may what you want. Basically, you can declare virtual functions in a base common to both Grandma and Dad ('Person'?) and Grandma can call those functions even if only Dad provides an implementation when you're using a Me object. Even though Grandma would know nothing about Dad, when you use virtual inheritance any subclasses your final class pulls in can be used to satisfy virtual functions from the virtual base class.